# Как сделать php скрипт на загрузку файла по request

Tags: php

И так, у меня есть код на java для создания POST запроса, где один из параметров это файл
Мне нужно чтобы по запросу `example.com/uploadfile.php?file="filepath"` происходила загрузка файла на сервер

Comment: А как вы содержимое файла то передаете ? или куда ведет этот filepath который в параметрах

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: `filepath` это что? URL-файла, который сервер пхп скрипт должен скачать, или это локальное имя файла, который должен считать и отправить ваш java-бэкенд ?

Answer (score 0):

Всё достаточно просто.

Для начала нужно проверить, есть ли файл, потом забрать его из временной папки, дать имя и расширение, и положить куда нужно:

```
if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0)
{
    $dir = "path_to_file/" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $dir);

}
else
{
    ecit("error!");
}
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: Не работает, сделал этот запрос example.com/uploadfile.php?file=C:\Users\romaz\Desktop\458.txt, он ничего не делает, белый экран, никуда не сохраняет

Comment: в любом месте допишите `print_r($_FILES));` и отправьте сюда, посмотрим, что не так.

Comment: Array ( ) @ВиталийRS

Comment: @serverexe, значит, никакого файла обработчик не получил. Можете дополнительно вывести `print_r($_POST))`;

Comment: @serverexe, так же для того, что бы файл был получен в заголовках запроса обязательно нужно указать, что там `multipart/form-data`. 
Думаю, Ваша проблема будет решена после изучения ответов по этой ссылке: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469451/upload-files-from-java-client-to-a-http-server

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133160/discussion-between-server-exe-and--rs).

Comment: не работает, статус код 200, но ничего нету на сервере

Comment: даже код на python не делает это `r = requests.post(url="http://qqbies.xyz/uploadfile.php", json={"file": "index.php"})`

Comment: @serverexe, перейдите в чат https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133160/discussion-between-server-exe-and--rs